# Spring dependency inection or default value?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a class `Car` which has a dependency : `Motor`

My class `Car` is like this :

```
@Component
public class Car {

    private Motor motor;

    @Autowired
    public Car(Motor motor) {
        this.motor = motor;
    }

    public Car() {
        this.motor = new Motor("created by Car");
    }
```

I'm not sure how Spring manages what to do : using default/no-args constructor or constructor injection dependency ? Which motor instance should be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) documentation,

> The constructor with the greatest number of dependencies that can be satisfied by matching beans in the Spring container will be chosen. If none of the candidates can be satisfied, then a primary/default constructor (if present) will be used.

Meaning, in your case, if Spring boot container finds bean of `Motor` during bootstrapping (may be via `@Configuraton` or `@Component` etc, ) then your `Car` bean will get instantiated with constructor based DI & in this case default constructor won't be used for creating `Car` bean.

If there is no `Motor` bean available during creation of `Car` bean, then default constructor is used.

Answer (score 0):

spring always call by default no arg constructor make sure you annotate motar as Component